# Need help Google Login in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want my google login to redirect users to homepage after successfull login and save their logged in state. But couldnt do that with some gpt it.

Authprovider with the changenotifier

```
  class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
    bool _isAuthenticated = false;
    SharedPreferences _prefs;
    GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);

    AuthProvider(this._prefs) {
    _isAuthenticated = _prefs.getBool('isAuthenticated') ?? false;
     }

    bool get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated;

    Future<void> login() async {
     try {
     final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        if (googleUser?.email != null) {
          _isAuthenticated = true;
          _prefs.setBool('isAuthenticated', true);
          notifyListeners();
         }
        } catch (error) {
        print('Error signing in with Google: $error');
        }
         }

        Future<void> logout() async {
        await _googleSignIn.signOut();
        _isAuthenticated = false;
        _prefs.setBool('isAuthenticated', false);
        notifyListeners();
        }
        }

        class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

       return authProvider.isAuthenticated ? Homepage() : WelcomePage();
       }
       }
```

Here is the login in the welcome screen

```
        class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
          late AuthProvider authProvider;

        @override
        void initState() {
        super.initState();
        authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
        }
```

Gesture detecture to invoke the login

```
        onTap: () async {
            await authProvider.login();
          },
```

Comment: Try to take value from Shared preferences which you store in isAuthenticated key. And on that value you can navigate to home screen or welcome screen.

Comment: add this line after declare _prefs:
_prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();